# SCREEN_OFF Broadcast Receiver not firing inside of Service in separate process

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Here is my stuff:

```
public class NotificationSystem extends Service implements Runnable {

    private final Thread worker = new Thread(this);
    private boolean alreadyRunning = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        ScreenManager screenManager = new ScreenManager();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(screenManager, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!alreadyRunning) {
            worker.start();
            this.alreadyRunning = true;
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {

            System.out.println("Thread doing stuff");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private static class ScreenManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("Screen is off");
        }
    }

}
```

The broadcast receiver never fires when the screen toggles off, why?

Is there some problem if there is that broadcast receiver inside of a service? Do I need anything in the manifest for `SCREEN_OFF` to toggle?

Is it another magical decision that the Android core team did instead of me? Maybe firing a broadcast receiver drains battery, ey?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't got your question much but I got the answer for permission question of yours.

For working with Broadcast receivers you are always require to give a permission to AndroidManifest.xml which allows you to listen to state changes in your receiver. Also Register your receiver in your manifest file.

which is added by:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
```

I hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

It is a firmware bug.

It's not working on my phone, but it works fine in the emulator.

Go figure.